# MySQL Finding differences between columns not producing correct output

Tags: mysql

I have a table Instructor, with an InstructorID column

InstructorID  Rank      Salary
201586985   Professor   120000
386167477   Reader  100000
463249547   Reader  100000
466388906   Lecturer    80000
555010131   Professor   120000
685744439   Reader  100000
696335701   Lecturer    80000
836826630   Lecturer    80000
961874958   Professor   120000
997111094   Reader  100000

And a MentorIDS table with a mentorID column

MentorID
201586985
997111094
386167477
463249547
386167477
201586985
201586985
466388906
386167477
685744439
997111094
555010131
466388906
997111094
836826630
696335701
696335701
463249547
555010131
836826630
386167477
836826630
961874958
685744439
836826630
997111094
961874958
463249547
997111094
386167477
685744439
555010131
463249547
696335701
201586985
386167477
836826630
997111094
466388906
201586985
466388906
555010131
961874958
961874958
555010131
201586985
555010131
836826630
836826630
696335701
685744439
997111094
696335701
685744439
696335701
463249547
685744439
997111094
555010131
466388906
836826630
466388906
463249547
555010131
463249547
201586985
997111094
463249547
466388906
463249547
997111094
685744439
685744439
463249547
961874958
685744439
997111094
386167477
555010131
386167477
997111094
555010131
386167477
836826630
961874958
201586985
201586985
466388906
555010131
466388906
696335701
463249547
836826630
997111094
961874958
466388906
463249547
836826630
201586985
463249547

I want to find any InstructorIDs that are not in Mentor ID which I am trying to do like so

```
SELECT distinct  
InstructorID  
FROM  
Instructor Inner Join MentorIDS  
Where (Instructor.InstructorID) NOT IN (MentorIDS.MentorID);
```

But it keeps returning
386167477
463249547
466388906
555010131
685744439
696335701
836826630
961874958
997111094
201586985
I am not sure why this is happening because when you look, those InstructorIDs are obviously in MentorID. Any idea why this would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT InstructorID  
FROM Instructor i 
WHERE i.InstructorID NOT IN (SELECT m.MentorID FROM MentorIDS);
```

You can write similar logic with `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN`.  This seems closest to your attempt, though.